# Variable prints both Null and Not Null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**PHP Test**

```
$username = 'Matt';
scope($username); //pass Matt to scope

function scope($username = null) {

    // Not null
    if (!is_null($username)) {
        print $username;
    }
    // Is null
    else if (is_null($username)) {
        print 'null';
    }
}
```

Works correctly. It prints **Matt**, since that variable was passed.

**Laravel**

[Using Scopes with Laravel 5](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/06/23/using-scopes-with-laravel-5/)

Component

```
public function init() {
    $username = $this->param('username'); //Matt
    $this->applyUser($username); //pass to scope function
}
```

Model

```
public function scopeApplyUser($query, $username = null) {

    // Not null
    if (!is_null($username)) {
        print $username;
    }
    // Is null
    else if (is_null($username)) {
        print 'null';
    }

    return $query->where('username', $username);

}
```

It prints both **Matt** and **null** at the same time.

It returns query results only **null**.

[image: screenshot]

How is this possible?

Comment: Where are you calling this function from? Controller?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar A custom component I made, Results.php. It is with OctoberCMS.

Comment: I'm not sure how OctoberCms works. But generally in laravel it works when you call the function with model like Model::applyUser($username);

Comment: There is no way it runs both if and else case.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar It runs if(), prints matt, then runs else if() and prints null right in the browser.

Comment: if(!is_null) is true how come it executes else part?

Comment: Maybe it is printing matt somewhere else

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar Here's a screenshot of my code and the browser output. https://i.imgur.com/4mLtrRF.png

Comment: If you comment echo $username you are not seeing Matt?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar Correct, if I comment it out, Matt does not print. I don't understand how it can do both if and else at the same time.

Comment: Strange. Kindly check if you have called applyUser somewhere else

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar I changed it to applyTestUser to avoid any unknown duplicate conflict, it still does the same.

Comment: I'm still not sure why it prints both. I tried it locally and it prints just matt for me

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar It works under normal php, but when used under laravel component and model it does this. But it may also be something to do with the builder plugin in OctoberCMS.

Comment: Okay, instead of else if (is_null($username) just let it be else alone

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar else also gave the same result, prints Matt and null.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar I think I might know what is going on. OctoberCMS first calls my Component applyUser() and prints Matt, but then the Builder Plugin also calls applyUser() and gets a different result null. So I think I'm seeing print results from the function being called twice.